# Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Given the following component, when I press down on the age selector and change the value to 15, such that I render a form without the driver license field, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.
    at invariant (react-dom.development.js:55)
    at finishHooks (react-dom.development.js:11581)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:14262)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15103)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17817)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:17857)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:17113)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:17957)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:18808)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:18716)
    at flushInteractiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:18987)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2210)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4946)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:18974)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2217)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4923)
```

Example code below:

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');
  const [age, setAge] = useState(16);

  if (age < 16) {
    return (
      <div>
        Name:{' '}
        <input
          value={name}
          onChange={e => {
            setName(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <br />
        Age:{' '}
        <input
          value={age}
          type="number"
          onChange={e => {
            setAge(+e.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

  const [license, setLicense] = useState('A123456');

  return (
    <div>
      Name:{' '}
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={e => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      Age:{' '}
      <input
        value={age}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          setAge(+e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      Driver License:{' '}
      <input
        value={license}
        onChange={e => {
          setLicense(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The problem is that in the first render, 3 `useState` hooks were invoked - `name`, `age` and `license` but after the age is changed to a value below 16, the `useState` for `license` is no longer invoked, resulting in only the first 2 hooks being invoked. As the [React docs state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple `useState` and `useEffect` calls.

The order of the hooks being called is important, and if we write code that causes hooks to not be called, React will not be able to match the hook call with its values.

The solution is to move the `license` hook up to the top of the function so that it gets called regardless whether it is needed or not.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('Mary');
  const [age, setAge] = useState(16);
  const [license, setLicense] = useState('A123456');

  return (
    <div>
      Name:{' '}
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={e => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <br />
      Age:{' '}
      <input
        value={age}
        type="number"
        onChange={e => {
          setAge(+e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {age >= 16 && <span>
        <br />
        Driver License:{' '}
        <input
          value={license}
          onChange={e => {
            setLicense(e.target.value);
          }}
        /></span>
       }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I ran into the problem, solved it and shared the solution along and analysis with the community. It's apparently encouraged by StackOverflow founder - https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: +one @YangshunTay I'm glad you did, because I ran into this myself now

Comment: Thanks for this clear example! I've ran into this problem multiple times but your Q&A made me have an AHA moment that I've never had even with personal tutoring.

Comment: worked for me aswell, instead of putting a component inside a toggled component, i just assigned the component to a variable then used the variable in the component, thank you @Yangshun Tay

Answer (score 53):

I have resolved this issue by changing the order of React Hooks. The `useEffect` came after an early `return`.

So I have changed code from

```
function (){    
    const [loading ,setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    
    if (loading) {
        return "loading ....."
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if (condition) {
        doSomething();
      }
    }, []);
    
    return <div>component</div>
}
```

to

```
function (){    
    const [loading ,setLoading] = React.useState(false);
   
    useEffect(() => {
      if (condition) {
        doSomething();
      }
    }, []);
     
    if (loading){
      return "loading ....."
    }

    return <div>component</div>
}
```

So, when loading becomes true then `useEffect` will not run and that will throw error. But if I declare loading JSX element after `useEffect` then it will work.

Comment: If you will use eslint-plugin-react  it will spot such issues right a way https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you didn't run `useEffect` conditionally.

For example, if you have some code like the following:

```
if(condition) {
  useEffect(()=>{
    doSomething();
  }, []);
}
```

Then change it to

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(condition) {
    doSomething();
  }
}, []);
```

Then the error would not happen.

Answer (score 8):

So I also experienced this error, but it was not related to the hook being wrapped in a condition. Instead it was caused by me having bad key values.

I had a component that moved items from one list to another by dragging and dropping. However, some of those items were locked, so I simply removed the reference to my hook in those elements.

The issue was that I used the index as a key, thus when I dragged a new element on top it got the same key as the locked element, the value of ref was changed and React complained with the above error.

So my answer to those who come across this issue is - check whether you have truly unique keys!

Answer (score 4):

Today i have just met this error, i fixed it by change the position of hook: `useEffect()` from middle to header of function. And make sure **do NOT** use hook inside loop.

You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an optional second argument to useEffect:

```
      useEffect( () => {
        dispatch({type: 'GET_PAGE', slug: Param});
        setPagedata( data );
      });
```

TO

```
      useEffect( () => {
        dispatch({type: 'GET_PAGE', slug: Param});
      }, [Param]);

      useEffect( () => {
        setPagedata( data );
      }, [data]);
```

ANd it works!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the above error in my own react application, when I used the `useCallback` hook inside the render component (and crucially, within an if condition). Moving the hook outside of functional component resolved the error. The lesson: don't use hooks inside conditional statements.

Answer (score 1):

If you conditionally render, do not put component property data in between!

```
if (splashScreen)
  return <Spinner>Loading</Spinner>

//DO NOT PUT THEM HERE

return (
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const useStyle = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  subHeading: {
    lineHeight: 1.2
  },
  listItemTextStyle: {
    textTransform: "none"
  }
}));

export const getOmniDetails = (data) => {
  const classes = useStyle(); 

  return (
    <Typography className={classes.subHeading} component="p">
      User Name: {data.userName}
    </Typography>
  );
};

export default function OmniSearchDropdown(props) {
  const { users = [], openProfile } = props;
  const classes = useStyle();
  return (
    <ListItemText
      primary={
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.listItemTextStyle}>
          {r.displayName}
        </Typography>
      }
      secondary={getOmniDetails(r)} // wrong
    />
  );
}
```

I faced the same issue while I was using the **single** theme (`useStyle`) in two different components and I was calling `getOmniDetails()` as a function **which is wrong**.

I solved this issue by just converting the function into component  `<GetOmniDetails data={data}/>`.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you have hot reload (HMR) turned on and you're adding or deleting a useEffect. Just reload the page and the error will not be reproduced.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using useWindowDimensions hook directly in the return part of functionnal component with condition. Solve it by declaring a variable outside the return part and using the variable in the conditionnal rendering. Hope this can help!