# Early return issue with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have faced the `Invariant violation: rendered fewer hooks than expected` issue using react hooks. From the other answers, it is clear that hooks should not be called conditionally ([Uncaught Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement in React Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472795/uncaught-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-this-may-be-caused-by-an-acc)).

The case which caused the app crash:

```
const MyComponent = (item) => {
    const [itemState, setState] = useState(true);

    if (!item) {
        return null;
    }

    const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState(true);

    return (<div>{item.name}</div>)
}
```

As an attempt, I tried to fix it by moving the check prior to calling the hooks, e.g:

```
const MyComponent = (item) => {

    if (!item) {
        return null;
    }

    const [itemState, setState] = useState(true);
    const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState(true);

    return (<div>{item.name}</div>)
}
```

This seems to work and it never crashes.
I decided to install `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` to prevent similar cases in the future. Now it warns with a `React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. Did you accidentally call a React Hook after an early return?`

So my question is: should I always do the return `after` all the hooks are run? e.g:

```
const MyComponent = (item) => {

    const [itemState, setState] = useState(true);
    const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState(true);

    if (!item) {
        return null;
    }

    return (<div>{item.name}</div>)
}
```

If yes, why then it crashes if I return `between` first and seconds hooks and doesn't crash if I return `before` all the hooks?

Comment: `React Hook "useState" is called conditionally` as it says you cannot use `useState` conditionally. Also you are not using properly `useState` here `const [itemState, setState] = setState(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move all the hooks before or after the early return then you always have the same amount of hooks (none or 2) on every render. If you put one before and one after then you don't, when it returns early you have one hook and when you don't you have 2 hooks.

Putting the useState after the early return confuses the linter but it also kind of breaks your state. The state is reset when you early return and on next render don't.

In the following example a dot is added to "Hello World", when you toggle off and on then all the dots are gone. Defining setState **before** the early return will have you keep the dots.

```js
const { useState } = React;
function App({ wut }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setShow(s => !s)}>
        toggle
      </button>
      <MyComponent item={show} />
    </div>
  );
}
const MyComponent = ({ item }) => {
  if (!item) {
    return <div>no item</div>;
  }
  const [itemState, setItemState] = useState('Hello World');
  return (
    <div>
      {itemState}
      <button onClick={() => setItemState(s => s + '.')}>
        Add .
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response with the clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

Declare you states using `useState` at top without condition -

```
 const MyComponent = ({item}) => {
  const [itemState, setState] = useState(true);
  const [anotherState, setAnotherState] = useState(true);
  const [localItem, setLocalItem] = useState(item);
  return localItem == null ? <></> : <div>{item.name}</div>;
};
```

Look here for rules- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks

Comment: I understand I have similar in my example. I am just curious why does the second code example works without the error thrown, even though it is kind of same `conditional hooks call`.

Comment: You need to declare `useState` at top. Read the rules here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks