# React JS: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

I am trying to make authentication for a React JS project but, I am getting the following error:

> Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.

I was reading other questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015414/early-return-issue-with-react-hooks) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472795/uncaught-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-this-may-be-caused-by-an-acc)) but I guess my situation is different since I set all the `useState` once the component is created.

I have used different approaches to get this done but neither of them worked for me.

I added the methods in the `ContextWrapper` component like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { fetchLogin, fetchVerify } from "../fake-server";
import Context from "./context";

export default ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["token"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(cookies);
    if (cookies.token) {
      setToken(cookies.token);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      setCookie("token", JSON.stringify(token), { path: "/" });
    } else {
      removeCookie("token");
    }

    console.log(token);
  }, [token]);

  function login(email, password) {
    fetchLogin(email, password)
      /*.then(response => response.json())*/
      .then(data => {
        const decoded = jwt.decode(data.token);
        const token = {
          token: data.token,
          ...decoded
        };
        setToken(token);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error", error);
        setMessage({
          status: 500,
          text: error
        });
      });
  }

  function verify() {
    fetchVerify(cookies.token)
      /*.then(response => response.json())*/
      .then(data => {
        setToken(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setToken(null);
        setMessage({
          status: 500,
          text: error
        });
      });
  }

  function logout() {
    setToken(false);
  }

  const value = {
    login,
    verify,
    logout,
    token,
    message,
    setMessage,
    loading,
    setLoading
  };

  return <Context.Provider value={value}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};
```

And then this is my `Login` component:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Grid,
  Card,
  Typography,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  FormControl,
  TextField,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Context from "../context/context";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    height: "100vh",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center"
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  card: {},
  formControl: {
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  actions: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
}));

export default ({ history, location }) => {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  if (context.token) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    context.setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    context.login(email, password);
  }

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.title}>
              Login
            </Typography>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth>
              <TextField
                type="text"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Email"
                value={email}
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth>
              <TextField
                type="password"
                variant="outlined"
                label="Password"
                value={password}
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </FormControl>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="secondary">
              Login
            </Button>
          </CardActions>
        </form>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Here I created [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-stallman-2ghxk) to reproduce the error that happens when `login()` method is triggered. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `return <Redirect to="/" />;` before the `useEffect` in Login is the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move your condition under the `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {})

if (context.token) {
  return <Redirect to="/" />;
}
```

Because your `if` condition was affecting the subsequent hook below it, as it wouldn't run if `context.token` is true.
This violates the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Pro Tip: Add ESlint Plugin as suggested in the React-Docs to get those warnings/errors while you code.

Comment: well... maybe that works, but now I am getting `Maximum update depth exceeded.` due infinite reloads...

Comment: @Maramal well, that's another issue isn't it? your `Home` component have side effects inside the body of the component(`context.verify()`), move it to `useEffect` and also rethink your architecture

Comment: I guess it is another question ... So thanks for solving my first issue.

Comment: @Maramal No problem, the answer is right here though, you CANT have any side effects inside the component body, so no network calls, no state updates, move them to `useEffect`. and a better way will be to just not render the route if the user is not logged

Answer (score 1):

Move the redirect logic after the hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    context.setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (context.token) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
```

In your home component you are redirecting user if `userIsValid` id not `true`.  And this filed will always be undefined as it is not defined in `context`. Add this field in the context and try.

Hope this will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, l use `useWindowDimension` to get height within a `View`'s style. This mistake costs me more than 3 days of endless search until l realized useWindowDimension is a hook too. So the proper way to use it is this:

```
 const window = useWindowDimension();

 return (
    <View style={{ height: window.height, }} />
 );
```

Answer (score -1):

The error from console tells you exactly where the problem is. You can not create hooks conditionally. This hook is a problem and needs to appear before return statement. This probably means you should change loading condition to work as expected.

```
useEffect(() => {
    context.setLoading(false);
}, []);
```

Comment: where I create a hook conditionally?

Comment: You have if statement with return before hook from my comment. It means that hook will be created only after your if condition (context.token) is true.